# Finding target sum of three numbers - optimizing nested loops

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where, given an array of integers, I need to find sets of three numbers that add up to equal zero. The below solution works but isn't as optimal as I'd like and I am looking for ways to optimize it to avoid unnecessary processing.

What I am doing below is I am iterating through the all combinations of numbers while eliminating iterating through the same indices in each nested loop and I am checking if the three numbers in the inner most loop add up to zero. If yes, I am converting the array to a string and if the string isn't already in the results array I am adding it. Right before returning I am then converting the strings back to an array.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to further optimize this or if I missed out on some opportunity to implement better. I am not looking for a total refactor, just some adjustments that will improve performance.

```
var threeSum = function(nums) {
    const sorted = nums.sort();

    if(sorted.length && (sorted[0] > 0 || sorted[sorted.length-1] < 0)) {
        return [];
    }

    let result = [];

    for(let i=0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        for(let z=i+1; z < sorted.length; z++) {
            for(let q=z+1; q < sorted.length; q++) {
                if(sorted[i]+sorted[z]+sorted[q] === 0) {
                    const temp = [sorted[i], sorted[z], sorted[q]].join(',');

                    if(!result.includes(temp)) {
                        result.push(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result.map(str => str.split(','));
};
```

Sample Input: `[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]`

Expected Output: `[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]`

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a Map. More efficient for look ups than using `Array#includes()` and wouldn't need to convert strings back to arrays. Also seems like a single sort at beginning would cut out a sort of each sub array

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for the feedback, can you elaborate a bit on what you mean? how can I use map in this case and eliminate array includes? doesn't map just run a given function on each element in the array, how would this accomplish the same function as array includes?

Comment: You are thinking of `Array#map()`... I am talking about a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object

Comment: @charlietfl he's using the array as a key though, so he'd still need to serialize it

Comment: @user120242 Sure...join the array to string as key and store the array as value. Then it's a simple `myMap.has(joinedString)` to check if it exists or not

Comment: @charlietfl oh, you said to cut out the deserialization step, got it

Comment: @charlietfl, I appreciate the feedback, I am looking at the Map docs --- if I understand this correctly, I need to use a map object to store results and ensure there aren't any duplicates using `has` -- which should result in better performance?

Comment: Use join() for the keys in the Map...and store the actual sub array as value. Yes use `has()` and at the end You can simply destructure the values of the Map for final result

Comment: Also, I don't really understand why this is a good use case for using 'Map' instead of a default object... why does this have better performance?

Comment: Sure can use a plain object with same string keys/ array values. A hashmap object would be more efifcient look up than the array includes also. The Map API is a little more robust and simpler to code ( and read that code)

Comment: Map can be faster in some cases.  If the keys are homogeneous some engines have native-level optimizations that kick in.  If you're doing a challenge it might make a difference.  You can also use a sum lookup table cache (should be a drop-in memoization function) and some heuristics like breaking out of the loop when it's impossible any other numbers will bring it closer to 0

Comment: Really appreciate the advice guys, I am trying to go the Map and `has` route which will eliminate the need for `includes`. I like that approach, thank you.

Comment: @charlietfl, it looks like with your suggestion, I am still getting the same performance / time limit exceeded error. See the answer below.

Comment: If it's a challenge (time limit exceeded is a common message for those competition coding sites) you'll need to do some of the optimizations I mentioned.  Probably do a precache while sorting.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious optimisation is to precalculate the sum of the two first numbers just before the third nested loop. Then compare in the third loop if that number equals the opposite of the third iterated number.

Second optimisation is to take advantage of the fact that your items are sorted and use a binary search for the actual negative of the sum of the two first terms in the rest of the array instead of the third loop. This second optimisation brings complexity from O(N3) down to O(N2LogN)

Which leads to the third optimisation, for which you can store in a map the sum as key and as value, an array of the different pairs which sum to the sum so that each time you want to operate the binary search again, first you check if the sum already exists in that map and if it does you can simply output the combination of each pair found at that sum’s index in the map coupled with the negative sum.

Comment: Good advice, thank you -- it seems the optimization I am looking for is binary search, I'll give that a try.

Comment: If this answer suits your needs you can also mark it as answer ;) it’s good for the ego :D

Comment: thanks for the advice, can you post some code for your binary search approach?

Comment: Actually I think selfie’s solution would be even faster si there is still probably no need for some binary search code tailored to your situation. I would simply take his version. And you can indeed validate his answer since it’s imho the best.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's solution runs in `O(N³)` time with no additional storage.

The classic "use a hash table" solution to find the missing element can bring that down to `O(N²)` time with `O(N)` storage.

The solution involves building a number map using an object. (You could use a Map object as well, but then you can't be as expressive with `++` and `--` operators).  Then just an ordinary loop and inner loop to evaluate all the pairs.  For each pair, find if the negative sum of those pairs is in the map.

```
function threeSum(nums) {

    var nummap = {};    // map a value to the number of ocurrances in nums
    var solutions = new Set(); // map of solutions as strings

    // map each value in nums into the number map
    nums.forEach((val) => {
        var k = nummap[val] ? nummap[val] : 0; // k is the number of times val appears in nummap
        nummap[val] = k+1; // increment by 1 and update
    });

    // for each pair of numbers, see if we can find a solution the number map
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        var ival = nums[i];
        nummap[ival]--;

        for (let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            var jval = nums[j];
            nummap[jval]--;

            var target = -(ival + jval); // this could compute "-0", but it works itself out since 0==-0 and toString will strip the negative off

            // if target is in the number map, we have a solution
            if (nummap[target]) {

                // sort this three sum solution and insert into map of available solutions
                // we do this to filter out duplicate solutions
                var tmp = [];
                tmp[0] = ival;
                tmp[1] = jval;
                tmp[2] = target;

                tmp.sort();
                solutions.add(tmp.toString());
            }

            nummap[jval]++; // restore original instance count in nummap
        }
        nummap[ival]--;
    }

    for (s of solutions.keys()) {
        console.log(s);
    }

}

threeSum([9,8,7,-15, -9,0]);
```

Comment: Indeed this solution avoid the binary search bit in the solution I proposed which saves some algorithmic tediousness.

Answer (score 0):

```
var threeSum = function(unsortedNums) {
    const nums = unsortedNums.sort();

    if(nums.length && (nums[0] > 0 || nums[nums.length-1] < 0)) {
        return [];
    }

    const result = new Map();

    for(let i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for(let z=i+1; z < nums.length; z++) {
            for(let q=z+1; q < nums.length; q++) {
                if(nums[i]+nums[z]+nums[q] === 0) {
                    const toAdd = [nums[i], nums[z], nums[q]];            
                    const toAddStr = toAdd.join(',');

                    if(!result.has(toAddStr)) {
                        result.set(toAddStr, toAdd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Array.from(result.values());
};
```