# runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0x000000000000 overflowed to 0xffffffffffffffe8

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

The question was to find all unique triplets which give sum=0 in an array and return a vector with a list of all those unique triplets.
This was my class definition:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>>ans;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1; j<nums.size(); j++)
            {
                for(int k=j+1; k<nums.size(); k++)
                {
                    if(nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]==0)
                    {  
                       ans.push_back( {nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]} );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        set<int> s(ans.begin(),ans.end());
        ans.assign(s.begin(),s.end());
        return ans;
    }
};
```

And now I'm getting the above mentioned error. Can anyone please help me with a simple explanation of what I did wrong and suggest an alternative?

Comment: I'm surprised this line `set<int> s(ans.begin(),ans.end());` compiles for you. It doesn't for me.
`

Comment: There's a much faster way to solve this problem.  Put all the numbers in an `unordered_map` with key being number and value being the number of instances. Do that first.  Then for every pair of numbers in the set, look to see if the negative summation of the pair is also in the set.  Look here for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239250/finding-target-sum-of-three-numbers-optimizing-nested-loops/62239821#62239821

Comment: Which line of code does the debugger point to?

Comment: The debugger is pointing to the set line ```set<int> s(ans.begin(),ans.end());```